# Incorrect number of predictions when using single values using predict() function in [R] in the caret package

Tags: r-caret, predict

```
data(iris)
library(caret)
#Naive Bayes machine learning on iris data set
nb.iris <- train(Species ~.,data=iris,method="nb")
```

Now create some 'newdata', to check the number of predictions. Note the number of predicted values you should expect (for Iris species). If I provide 2 rows of data I should get 2 predictions etc.

Let's try feeding the model with 2 rows of data

```
multi.value <- iris[1:2,]
predict(nb.iris,multi.value)
#two predicted values returned (correct)
```

BUT a single row of data does not return a single predicted value!!

```
single.value <- iris[1,]
predict(nb.iris,single.value)
#FOUR predicted values returned - INCORRECT!!!
```

BUT if I duplicate this single value, I can get a (correct prediction) of that row of data

```
duplicate.single.value <- iris[c(1,1),]
predict(nb.iris,duplicate.single.value)
#TWO predicted values (correct)
```

This seems like a bug....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is as follows:
The data are coming into the prediction function as a matrix and was getting converted to the wrong format. The owner of the caret package has made a change to fix this.

For more information see [issue #345](https://github.com/topepo/caret/issues/345) on the caret github page.

As soon as the fix is in the package on cran I will update this answer.

## Edit:

Caret on cran has been updated. Issue is resolved in caret version 6.0-64